# Win10 system, using electron-app to open a shared folder, it gets stuck to the point where other apps won't open either, why?

Tags: windows-10, electron-vue

This electron-app has only one button, clicking on that button will execute the following 3 commands to trigger the opening of the shared folder

1. `net use * /delete`
2. `net use \\\share.yafex.cn /user:mycompany\username password`
3. `explorer.exe \\\xxx.xxx.cn\share`

Then the win10 system gets stuck, causing other apps to lag and not open either

Guys, is there any possible reason for this?

But when I don't use electron-app, but directly use cmd to execute these three commands directly in win10 system, this won't happen.